# How can I implement the same method for different sets of traits?

Tags: data-structures, rust, traits, implementation

Let's say I have a generic struct that looks like this:

```rust
struct MyStruct<T> {
    value: T
}
```

I want to do A Thing (TM), but its only possible with certain trait implementations. So, I have:

```rust
impl<T: Trait1> MyStruct<T> {
    pub fn do_thing(&self) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But not every `T` implements `Trait1`, so I also want to cover `Trait2`, etc. as a backup option.

```rust
impl<T: Trait2> MyStruct<T> {
    pub fn do_thing(&self) {
        // do the same thing in a different way
    }
}
```

This solution doesn't work, as I'd have duplicate definitions for `do_thing()` for any `T` that implements both `Trait1` and `Trait2`, and there's no way to know which one to use by default.

So, is there some way that I can specify the fallback order to tell the compiler which implementation of `do_thing()` to use? Or should I be approaching this from a completely different angle?

Comment: What should happen if you have a Type `T` implementing `Trait1` and `Trait2`? Which method should `(MyStruct { value: T }).do_thing()` resolve to?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in stable rust. <s>Nightly [specializatio](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html)n feature might help you, if you can make one `T` more strictly defined then the other one (e.g. `T: Trait1 + Trait2` for high priority implementation and `T: Trait1` for default implementation).</s>

EDIT: I played a little with `specialization` and it seems like it's impossible to implement what you want even with it.

If you want to stick with stable, you would probably need to have different methods. This is possible only if the consumer of this struct know for sure which type T it uses, but if it is your case, it's the best option.

```
impl<T: Trait1> MyStruct<T> {
  pub fn do_thing(&self) {}
}

impl<T: Trait2> MyStruct<T> {
  pub fn do_another_thing(&self) {}
}
```

I would say that the most Rusty way to implement different function logic for different types is to use `enums` instead of generics.

```
struct MyStruct {
  value: MyEnum,
}

enum MyEnum {
  SimpleThing{...},
  MoreComplicatedThing{...},
}

impl MyStruct {
  do_thing(&self) {
    match self.value {
      MyEnum::SimpelThing{..} => self.do_simple_thing(),
      MyEnum::MoreComplicatedThing{..} => self.do_more_complicated_thing(),
    }
  }
}
```